# ComboBox don't update

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I got a `comboBox` in FORM1 that gets the value from the database

**FORM1 Code:**

```
public void fillComboBox()
{           
    using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
    {
         myDatabaseConnection.Open();
         using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select LastName, FirstName, MiddleName from EMP", myDatabaseConnection))
         using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (sqlreader.Read())
             {
                 string Lname = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));
                 string Fname = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                 string Mname = sqlreader.GetString(sqlreader.GetOrdinal("MiddleName"));
                 string fullName = Lname + ", " + Fname + " " + Mname; 
                 comboBox3.Items.Add(fullName);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

From the FORM1 I have a `button` that opens the FORM2 where I could add data in the database.

**FORM2 Code:**

```
public void addData()
{
    string a = "INSERT INTO Emp(LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) Values('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '"+textBox3.Text+"')";

    using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection1 = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
    {
         myDatabaseConnection1.Open();
         using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" " + a + " ", myDatabaseConnection1))
         mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }  
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addData();
    Form1 nf = new Form1();
    nf.fillComboBox();
    this.close
}
```

I check the database and verified the data is added.
The problem is when I add data in the datatabase the comboBox don't update the data it loads. It only updates after I run the program again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code:

```
Form1 nf = new Form1();
nf.fillComboBox();
```

You are creating a new `Form1` after db update (and not showing it). You are not refreshing the original `Form1`.

To see this, add: `nf.Show();` after the fillComboBox() call.

You have to refresh the original `Form1` after closing `Form2`.

example:

```
if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    fillComboBox();
```

and in `fillComboBox`, you should clear `comboBox3.Items` before adding new entries.